# i cant use method store in laravel framework

Tags: laravel, post

i am learning to myself laravel framework, and now i am trying to save data in a table, However it does but it gives me the error 
**Fatal error-Use of undefined constant users - assumed 'users'**

Sending the form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('users.store')}}">
```

and in the method store:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Exception;
class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
      $data=User::all();
      return view ('index',compact('data'));
    }



    public function create()
    {

        return view('create');
        }



    public function store(Request $request)
    {
           try{
               $user=new User();
               $user->name=$request->name;
               $user->email=$request->email;
               $user->password=  bcrypt($request->password);
               $user->save();
               return redirect()->route(users.index);

           } catch (Exception $e) {
                return "Fatal error-" .$e->getMessage();
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect, you're missing the quotes:

```
return redirect()->route(users.index);
```

change to

```
return redirect()->route('users.index');
```

Comment: Thanks ! it was the problem, i am begining to use a framework, i always program in php without framework.